# jquery problems with append

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have a function to load and place images into an empty div (it's some kind of scrolling menu done by me) and to place images one behind another I use append function. All is going well until the upload to the server. The order of the pictures seems to be failed like the append() is not placing them one behind another.

```
loadContent = function(i){
    var tytul = "#phot" + i;
    var photurl = "../photos/" + activegal + "/" + i + ".JPG";
    $.ajax({
        url:photurl,
        type:'HEAD',
        error: function()
        {

        },
        success: function()
        {
            newid = "photo"+i;
            var img = $("<img />").attr({

                src: photurl,
                width:"120",
                height:"90",
                id: newid,
                'class': "photon"
            });
            $(img).appendTo("#scrollbar");
            counter++;  
            //$.delay(2);
        });   
};

<div id="scrollbar">
        </div>
```

Comment: *"until the upload to the server"*? where is the code that uploads to server..?

Comment: I upload the file by FTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you are trying to do a get on the images in an ajax call through a loop counter  and then add these image elements to the `<div>` element,  however ajax calls being asynchronous , the appendTo()  of image#1  might be called after appendTo of image#2 depending on when each of the ajax calls returns (which in turn might depend on the size of the image, network traffic etc.).

The only way to ensure the   elements are in order of server checks is by making the ajax calls synchronous by setting:

**async:   false**

Comment: And where do I put it?